# How can a database table be created before a database?

Tags: sql-server

I have an odd situation where a mystery table has appeared in my db. The db was create in 2018 but the table looks like it was created in 2015! How can this happen or has something just screwed up somewhere?

Comment: What table is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the table has been created in the `model` database on that server.

SQL Server doesn't create databases from scratch. It copies [`model`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/model-database?view=sql-server-2017). Occasionally this is useful if you want to have standard auditing structures, say, applied to all user databases. I haven't often used it.

Comment: Thanks, that appears to be the issue. Will mark as correct after the designated waiting time.